# libcublas.so.11 file missing after installing cuDNN successfully and libcublas.so.12 being present

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia, cudnn

I'm trying to install cuDNN on my Ubuntu 22.10 machine, I've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html) on how to install it using the package manager.

The installation has worked fine and I was able to compile the `mnistCUDNN` example like in step 1.4.

But unfortunately when I run the compiled `mnistCUDNN` binary I get the following error:

```
Could not load library libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8. Error: libcublas.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable is set to the following path `/usr/local/cuda-12.0/lib64`

When I check that directory there is a file called `libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8` as well
as the following versions of `libcublas.so`:

```
libcublas.so
libcublas.so.12
libcublas.so.12.0.2.224
```

so there is a version 12 file but no `libcublas.so.11` like in the error message.

No I'm wondering why that file is missing or why it can't work with the existing `libcublas.so.12`.

`nvidia-smi` works fine too and tells me that I have cuda version 12 running.

Comment: Are you trying to get CUDA 12.x to work as CUDA 11.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but I had to manually copy the contents of the cuDNN tar file like described [here in section 1.3.1](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installlinux-tar) on top of the package manager installation. After doing this everything works.

```
$ sudo cp cudnn-*-archive/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda-12.0/include 
$ sudo cp -P cudnn-*-archive/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda-12.0/lib64 
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda-12.0/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda-12.0/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Make sure to check if the the directory of your cuda installation differs.

The tar file is available for download [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download).